# Using the Gaussian copula to evaluate risk in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

So I'm trying to apply a Gaussian copula to a Monte Carlo simulation of loan values. By simulating a random number and checking whether or not it is under the decimal probability of failure. This when works when I supply a model portfolio(100 loans with the same probability) but when I enter the actual portfolio of different probs the mean of the result doesn't match. Should be 0.077 ends up closer to 0.088. Here is the code, would appreciate help

```py
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import seaborn as sns
    import csv
    from scipy.stats import norm

     dl = pd.read_csv('loan_portfolio.csv')
     dl.head


    def Gauss(p, n, rho):
        t = 0
        z = np.zeros(n)
        u = np.zeros(n)
        y = np.random.normal()
        for ii in range(n):
            z[ii] = np.sqrt(rho) * y + np.sqrt(1 - rho) * np.random.normal()
            u[ii] = norm.cdf(z[ii])
        for ii in range(n):
            e = u[ii]
            if e <= p[ii]:
                t = t + 1
            else:
                t = t
        return (t)


    with open('tally.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
     
   writer.writerow(["Defaulted"])
    for i in range(1, 100001):
         
   writer.writerow([Gauss(dl.pd_decimal, 120, 0)])

    dt = pd.read_csv('tally.csv')
    dt.head()
    print(dt.describe())
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, the issue turned out to be that the number of sample's was not one hundred and was causing a discrepancy